# VS 2022 generates double moc.obj files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, moc

If I try to compile a simple Qt project, I receive 6 linking errors:

```
mocs_compilation_Release.obj : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@MainWindow@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) già definito in moc_mainwindow.obj
1>mocs_compilation_Release.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl MainWindow::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@MainWindow@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ) già definito in moc_mainwindow.obj
1>mocs_compilation_Release.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual int __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@MainWindow@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z) già definito in moc_mainwindow.obj
1>mocs_compilation_Release.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual void * __cdecl MainWindow::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@MainWindow@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z) già definito in moc_mainwindow.obj
1>mocs_compilation_Release.obj : error LNK2005: "public: static struct QMetaObject const MainWindow::staticMetaObject" (?staticMetaObject@MainWindow@@2UQMetaObject@@B) già definito in moc_mainwindow.obj
1>E:\C++project\QT\GraphingCalculator\VSProject\Release\Calculator.exe : fatal error LNK1169: rilevato uno o più simboli definiti più volte
```

If I see the folder where `.obj` files are generated, they are there; for example, in the *release* folder, there are 2 files, which I presume contain the same information:

- `moc_mainwindow.obj`
- `moc_mainwindow_relase.obj`

I use:

- CMake
- VS2022 with Qt extension installed

I tried to delete all `.obj` files and rebuild, but nothing changed.

CMake:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

project(GraphingCalculator)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

file(GLOB resource *.cpp *.h *.c *. hpp *.qrc *.ui)

find_package(Qt6widgets REQUIRED)

add_executable(Calculator ${resource})

target_link_libraries(Calculator Qt6::Widgets)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    
    (new MainWindow())->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <Qpushbutton>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QPushButton* button;
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent = 0);
};

#endif
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(0)
{
    button = new QPushButton("Close", this);
    QObject::connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), QApplication::instance(), SLOT(quit()));

    setFixedSize(100, 100);
}
```

There's also a `.qrc` file, but it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem using a differnet cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(Graphing_Calculator, VERSION 0.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
qt_standard_project_setup()
file(GLOB resource *.cpp *.h *.c *. hpp *.qrc *.ui)
qt_add_executable(Graphing_Calculator ${resource})
target_link_libraries(Graphing_Calculator PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets)
set_target_properties(Graphing_Calculator PROPERTIES
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE ON
)
```

I don't know why but in this mode all work goods!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).